# Fetch data from an excel file and make an editable data grid

Tags: django, datagrid

I am planning to use django. I am provided a task to fetch data from an excel sheet and display it as an editable datagrid on a web page on page load. In grid few fields will already contain data and User need to provide data in few fields in the grid and then after performing some calculations on the frontend itself, one more field will be filled and on clicking save the data should be saved in the excel file. Next time user visit the page he should see the earlier data in the grid. I am not getting how to approach this problem. deadline is coming Sunday. Please suggest how can I achieve this or any sample code will be very helpful. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Check out https://datatables.net/.

Comment: @Bobort I can't find any example with django at the link

Comment: it would be really helpful if someone can provide some example with code snippets

Comment: Sorry, @Suraj.  After reading your post more carefully, I get the impression that you want someone to do your homework.  You'll fare much better at programming when you do it yourself.  datatables provides a grid editor at a monetary cost.  The datagrid is all handled on the frontend.  Django doesn't do much on the frontend; just return rendered templates.  Based on what you have presented, you will need more than a few days to complete this project.  Good luck!